# Extract manifest file from an application before installation

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-install-apk, apktool

Is there any tools or library in Android SDK that allows me extract a manifest file from an Android application during its installation time (before accepting the permissions demands)?

The extraction process must be done in the device is not in a third-party machine.
I want to do this to be able to collect these files for academic research.

Comment: there is no such specific tool I'm sure.

Comment: Developing an application with root privilege privileges could do this for applications already installed (or during installation as I truly want it) ?

Comment: `with root privilege` could do anything.

Comment: Ok, I'll see if there are antivirus on Android that can make scans (before or after installing an application) and see if they have root privileges or not and I'll see if I can do The same thing by developing a simple (homemade) application that recovers the desired manifest file, but I am always taking any other proposal

Answer (score 1):

If the processing to be done on the manifest file is to retrieve the requested permissions, I believe you can do this by making a change in Android OS, in the **checkPermission** method of the **PackageManagerService** class, you can retrieve the requested permissions from The application to install, you need to save it in an object such as string list.

In this sense, making changes on Android OS, I think you can retrieve the manifest file from applications to install, I do not know if this is easy or not, I let you discover and hope that my proposal will give you Another track to dig

Comment: Your answer is interesting , but to make changes in the OS is the last solution to opt, however, I am taker of any other proposal :)